# performs a recursive binary search on an ordered array

Tags: assembly, motorola

I want to write a  subroutine that performs a recursive binary search on an ordered array of 16 bit two's complement words. I have most of the code, all i need to do now is write a recursive binary search subroutine. any help?

```
int binSearch(int key, int &lo, int &hi) {
    if(hi < lo)
       return NOT_FOUND;  //RETURN with V = 1  
    int mid = (lo+hi) / 2;
    if(key == array[mid])
       return mid;
    else if(key < array[mid]) // go left
       return binSearch(key, lo, mid-1); // left
    else
       return binSearch(key, mid+1, hi); // right
    }
```

Im trying to put that to assembler.

```
link        A6,#0
    movem.l        D1/A1-A2,-(sp) *this is right
    move.w        8(A6),D1   *key *this is right
    movea.l        10(A6),A1  *lo*this is right
    movea.l        14(A6),A2  *hi*this is right

    cmpa.l        A1,A2 *if hi>lo
    BHS            else
    move.l        A1,D1 *low D1
    add.l        A2,D1 *adds hi
    asr.l        #1,D1 * divide by 2
    andi.w        #$FFFE,D1 * I dont cras
```

h 
the part here I have some right, How DO i do  if(hi < lo)

Comment: So, you have most of the code, except the code that does the thing you want to do?

Comment: Yeah what I have aks me to load the array, which it does then it searches the array then it just crashes.

Comment: Edit your post to include your code and any information you have about the crash.

Comment: "How DO i do if(hi < lo)" do you haven't a `jb/jl` instruction? I'm not familitar to motora's assembly language,but in intel is something like this: `cmp eax,ebx jl .label` it jump to `.label` if `eax < ebx`.

Comment: is that a jump instruction? I need to call a subroutine somwhere right?